# What is the best algorithm to find longest substring with constraints?

Tags: string, algorithm

Unfortunately I don't know the name of following problem but I am sure that it is well known problem. I want to find effective algorithm to solve problem.

Let S - input string and K - some number (1 <= K <= 26).

Problem is to find longest substring of S, which has only K different characters. What is the best algorithm to solve this problem?

Some examples:

1) S = aaaaabcdef, K = 3, answer = aaaaabc

2) S = acaaba, K = 2, answer = acaa or aaba

3) S = abcde, K = 5, answer = abcde

I have sketch of solution of this problem. But it seems too difficult for me, also it has quadratic complexity. So, in single linear pass I can compute sequent of the same characters by one and appropriated count. Next step is to use set which will contain only K characters. Usage is similar:

```
std::string max_string;
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
{
   std::set<int> my_set;
   std::string possible_solution;
   for (int j = i; j < s.size(); ++j)
   {
       // filling set and possible_solution
   }
   if (my_set.size() == K && possible_solution.size() > max_string.size())
      max_string = possible_solution; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have constraints on the input? Will quadratic solution suffice?

Comment: "Best algorithm" is probably off-topic for here, but if you make an attempt at an answer (eg, I think it is relatively trivial with a single pass through the data), you will get suggestions on how to improve the code.

Comment: I am interested in fastest algorithm as possible

Comment: @KenY-N I can't think of a solution that does a single linear pass. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I will explain my idea

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Now I think more, I am incorrect, but a single pass with simple look-ahead up to K unique characters forward would suffice.

Comment: Hint: keep track of first and last occurrence of each letter in the current candidate substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation:
  `s` = input string, zero-based index
  `[start, end)` = substring of input from start to end, including `start` but excluding `end`
  `k-substring` = a substring that contains **at most** k different characters

Algorithm: linear complexity `O(n)`

```
start = 0
result = empty string
find max(end): [start, end) is a k-substring
LOOP:
  // please note in every loop iteration, [start, end) is a k-substring
  update result=[start, end) if (end-start) > length(result)
  if end >= length(s) then DONE! EXIT
  increase start until [start, end) is a (k-1)-substring
  increase end while [start, end] is a k-substring
ENDLOOP
```

To check if increasing start or end respectively decrease or increase the character pool size (*k property*), we can use a count[] array, where count[c] = number of occurence of c in the current substring [start, end).

C++ Implementation: http://ideone.com/i2JPCq

Comment: I am observing your code. For such input: aaaaab, 3 the answer is aaaaab

Comment: It is pretty simple implementation. I am voting for this answer. But I am not sure about linear complexity

Comment: `end` and is running from 0 to len(s), and `start` from 0 to some value < len(s), so it is linear. And I'm pretty sure it is as fast as one can get.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can come up with is with time complexity O(log(n) * n)) and additional memory complexity O(n). The idea is the following:

First for all 26 characters compute a prefix sum array. For the character C this array has the following property a<sub>0</sub> = 0, a<sub>i</sub> = `<number of occurrences of C up to position i>`. It is very easy to compute this:

```
a[0] = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
  a[i] = a[i - 1] + (s[i - 1] == C)
}
```

Now let us assume you have these arrays. It is very easy to compute the number of occurrences of the character C in a closed interval [i, j]. This is precisely `a[j + 1] - a[j]`. Using this you can also check if C appears somewhere in the interval [i, j] -  simply check if the count of the occurrences is greater than 0.

The last part of my solution is to use binary search. For each index i in the string use binary search to identify what is the longest length of substring starting at position i that has no more than K different characters. The complexity of this part of the algorithm is O(n * log(n)).

Comment: Interesting approach, But can you explain last step more precisely, please?

Comment: As I understood, on each step of binary search we should use 26 checks to test that substring has no more than K different characters?

Answer (score 1):

Since your alphabet consists of only 26 letters, a linear time algorithm can be as follows:

Scan the string from left to right, at each step maintain two separate arrays startIndex[26], endIndex[26].

```
startIndex[i] = index of first instance of ('a' + i)th letter in the current active substring.  
endIndex[i] = index of last instance of ('a' + i)th letter in the current active substring.
```

You can initialize the arrays elements to be any strange value (like -1) to check their validity during the algorithm.
Also, maintain the maximum length of sub-string obtained so far and the number of current active unique characters.

Algorithm:

```
1. i = 0. 
   - Mark the startIndex and endIndex of S[0]. 
   - Initialize maxLength = 1
   - Initialize activeChars = 1.
2. for i = 1 to S.size()-1
   - if (S[i] != any of the activeChars) // can be done in O(26)
          if (activeChars == K)
              update maxLength if maxLength < currLength.
              remove an active char with least startIndex.
              add this new char to startIndex and endIndex
              currLength = i - min (remaining active startIndex) + 1
          else
              activeChars++;
              add this S[i] to startIndex and endIndex
              currLength++.          
              update maxLength if maxLength < currLength.
    else
       update endIndex for S[i].       
       currLength++.          
       update maxLength if maxLength < currLength.
3. again update maxLength if maxLength < currLength.
```

Comment: It seems too difficult for me. But compexity of this algorithm is awesome. I will check it out

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко The idea is to maintain a kind of a queue of distinct characters being considered currently. Whenever you find a K+1th distinct character, you will have to remove the occurences of the 1st character found from your current substring.

Comment: if (activeChars == K) remove an active char with least startIndex; I think this is wrong. What if the char you're removing is present many times and also more forward in the active substring (you end up considering a substring with K+1 different chars)? Shouldn't you remove the active char with the least END index, and start counting the substring from the END index of the char you removed to the just added new char?

Comment: @Matt No, we should remove the char that has the least startIndex because that was the char that was encountered first. For instance in string aabbbbccaabbcc we will have to remove 'a' before 'b' or 'c'.

Comment: In the string "aabbccaad" if you remove 'a' and count from the remaining startIndex of the others you obtain "bbccaad" substring that has k+1 different chars

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to modify Abhishek Bansal's algorithm to keep linear complexity and patch the errors that could arise with repeated characters in the active group.

Scan the string from left to right, at each step maintain two separate arrays startIndex[26], endIndex[26], and a map where you associate each char(key) to all its occurencies in the active substring(value).

```
startIndex[i] = index of first instance of ('a' + i)th letter in the current active substring  
endIndex[i] = index of last instance of ('a' + i)th letter in the current active substring.
map.get(i) = list of occurencies in considered substring.
```

Algorithm:

```
1. i = 0. 
   - Mark the startIndex and endIndex of S[0], add the occurency of S[0] to the map. 
   - Initialize maxLength = 1
   - Initialize activeChars = 1.
2. for i = 1 to S.size()-1
   - if (S[i] != any of the activeChars) // can be done in O(26)
          if (activeChars == K)
              update maxLength if maxLength < currLength.
              remove the active char with least endIndex.
              add this new char to startIndex and endIndex, and to the map with this occurency
              remove from the map all the occurencies of all the chars that are previous than removed char's endIndex
              update all the startIndex referring to the edited map
              currLength = i - min (remaining active startIndex) + 1
          else
              activeChars++;
              add this S[i] to startIndex and endIndex and to the map
              currLength++.          
              update maxLength if maxLength < currLength.
    else
       update endIndex for S[i], add the occurency to the map.       
       currLength++.          
       update maxLength if maxLength < currLength.
3. again update maxLength if maxLength < currLength.
```

I kept startIndex and endIndex arrays for clarity sake, but you could avoid the extra space and the extra work to update them using the first and the last element of the list of occurencies  stored in the map for the key == char C.